# Checking vertex property equivalency in Gremlin / TitanDB

Tags: titan, gremlin

If I can check the value of a property like this:

`g.V().hasLabel('appUser').has('myId','1234').values('isPrivate')
==>false`

But when I check if that value is `false` within an `if`, doesn't return what I would expect:

`if(g.V().hasLabel('appUser').has('myId','1234').values('isPrivate') == 'false'){'is false'}else{'is true'}
==>is true`

Similarly, this also doesn't return what I would expect:

`if(!g.V().hasLabel('appUser').has('myId','1234').values('isPrivate')){'is false'}else{'is true'}
==>is true`

How should I update this to perform a conditional check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.values()` returns a `Traversal`, which is an `Iterable` ([see TinkerPop 3.1.1 JavaDoc](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/javadocs/3.1.1-incubating/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversal.html#values-java.lang.String...-)). You have to call `.next()` in order to actually retrieve the property value.

The provided query can be written like this.

```
if(!g.V().hasLabel('appUser').has('myId','1234').values('isPrivate').next()){'is false'}else{'is true'}
```

Notice the call to `.next()` right after `.values('isPrivate')`.

When using the Gremlin Console, `Traversal` objects are automatically iterated (`.iterate()`), so what looks magical actually isn't. Mid-script (or outside of the Gremlin Console), you have to `.next()` or `.iterate()` the Traversal yourself in order to execute it, whether that Traversal is meant to retrieve elements (like the current use case) or mutate the graph.